# How to reference a Popup IE window using InternetExplorer.Application in VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, popup, wsh

I have a VB script which is run from the command line; the script opens a website populates the tracking number field and executes the onclick event of a button which returns the tracking events in a PopUp Window.

How do I reference the Popup windows so I can Parse the results?

```
set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie           
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "http://tracksomething.com/getthatnumber.ashx?Types=SH,&NetworkId=30129&Size=Small&Color=btn%20btn-primary&Language=EN"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
    Loop

    Set trknum = .document.getElementByID("transactionNumberId")
    trknum.Value = rst("trknum") ' change this to yours
    Set button = .document.getElementByID("getTtansactionScriptButton")
    button.click

    Wscript.Sleep 2000

    Content = .Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).InnerText
    ts.WriteLine Content

End With
```

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VBScript

Comment: @Plutonix thanks the system defaulted  with the VB.NET tag.